# Can we Loop within a subscribe method?

Tags: angular, ngrx

```
 this.schoolCareerStore = this.SchoolPageStateStore.select('School_Sections_Text').subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log("school_Career_store",data)
        this.test2=data.Video
        console.log(this.test2)
        for(let value of this.test2)
        {
            if(value.type='youtube')
            {
                this.test1=value.number
                this.test==`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.test1}`;
                console.log('this is the url',this.test)
            }
        }

    });
```

// As when i try....... that is not executed...if there is a way which can done please enlighten?? Thanks in advance

Comment: There’s a typo: `if(value.type='youtube')` should be `===`. And also `this.test==` should be `this.test =`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below change will hep you:

```
 this.schoolCareerStore = 
   this.SchoolPageStateStore.select('School_Sections_Text').subscribe((data)=>{
    this.test2=data.Video;
    for(let value of this.test2)
    {
        if(value.type=='youtube')
        {
            this.test1=value.number;
            this.test==`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.test1}`;
        }
    }

});
```

In the condition you need to have `==` or `===`. `==` will check only the value (not the type). But `===` will check both value and type. Changed just `if(value.type='youtube')` to `if(value.type=='youtube')`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You still got the typo in `this.test==` …

Comment: Can you share the code via stackblitz or some other way. I think I can debug and see. Else send the exact error you are getting in console. Also share the scope as well (Can you check what is scope of this... Just debug and try to console this)

Comment: Anoop Rajasekhara...thanks for your reply.....it took me sometime to check my question as i was able to achieve it in the html file itself....but i tried by rectifying the typos still the problem persists...."Also share the scope as well "....i didnot understand can you please elaborate what you meant....as i cant share the code....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run loops in subscribe. I think it's not working due to the typos in line no 7 and 10. For comparing the values use **==** and comparing with the same type use **===**. For assigning the value use **=** instead.

```
this.schoolCareerStore = this.SchoolPageStateStore.select('School_Sections_Text').subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log("school_Career_store",data);
        this.test2=data.Video;
        console.log(this.test2);
        for(let value of this.test2)
        {
            if(value.type==='youtube')
            {
                this.test1=value.number;
                this.test=`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.test1}`;
                console.log('this is the url',this.test);
            }
        }

    });
```